# Humans desire riches, fame, power and... (wo)men?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

*"Riches, power, fame and women"* are umbrella words [often used](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0525126759) for describing the things that most people aspire to get. The lowest of our core humans desires: Material possessions, control over others, recognition, respect and ego-related desires, and carnal desire.

I usually have a problem with the latter and I struggle to find a proper substitution.

To quote a [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/115950/why-would-magic-users-not-try-to-take-over-kingdoms?noredirect=1#comment356144_115950) from worldbuilding that recently reminded me of this issue:

> (...)But, it would make sense that at least a few wizards would want to use their powers to gain riches, fame, women and power.

Here, I read the word **women** to mean "people who satisfy their sexual desires", which... doesn't necessarily need to be female. Or... humans, but that goes beyond the scope of this question.

**I don't feel like "women" is an appropriate umbrella term to use**

### Why it doesnt work: Sexism

I consider this an inappropiate term due to sexist connotations an historical objectification of the gender. Yes, people are being objectified on the context of the sentence but one shouldn't need to reference a historical objectified group for referencing a common human desire, understandably alienating a wide portion of your audience.

### Why it doesnt work: Context

It also doesn't really work in many contexts, since it makes way too many assumptions about the targets, like their sexual preference. For instance, in the first example it gives the impression that all the wizards (or at least the offending ones) are straight males, which may or may not be the author's intent.

**What would be a better broad term to use in this context?**

*Note: It can be multiple words as long as it sounds natural*

Comment: Why not redact that inappropriate word in the question then?

Comment: @Kris Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You could use a dummy word, any word, in the place, if you do not want to use an offensive word.

Comment: @Kris Yes... I agree... finding such word is the point of my question... (?)

Comment: Your reference is a '79 book title.  Arguing such is laden with opinion.

Comment: @lbf I also reference a 2018 Stack Overflow question. From experience, I've read those words (or small variations, like "money" or "gold" instead of "riches") used together many times. I'll try to provide more uses but I think it shouldn't be necessary for the context of this question.

Comment: power, wealth. fame and sexual conquests is the idea. Sexual conquest is politically correct and fits the bill.

Comment: @Lambie I like it! Would you write it as an answer? :)

Comment: Just say it: riches, fame, power, and sex.

Comment: I suppose “love” is not even a consideration (or is it?). Is “companionship” too milquetoast? How about “conjugal companionship”, or, obviously, “sexual companionship”?

Comment: Your assumption that wizards may be of either sex is not automatically justified. Historically (and in Harry Potter) *wizard* meant 'male magic-user' ;a female magic-user was a *witch*.

Comment: @TimLymington even so, the assumption that all male magic-users are exclusively interested in female companionship is not-done in this day and age either...

Comment: Stop and think.  You've got someone who strongly desires riches, fame, and power.  Isn't it highly likely that this person is a male and is sexist?

Comment: @HotLicks It might be, but let's not forget that every human (or, for that matter, self-aware creature) has the potential to be selfish and/or evil, no matter their gender, sexual inclinations and/or favourite dinosaur.

Comment: In my viw, this has nothing to do with English… it's purely about personal preference, in whatever language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just say "sex", unless you think that what the wizards are interested in is romance and long-term companionship rather than immediate gratification.

An example where this is used in popular culture is the phrase *sex, drugs, and rock'n'roll*, which describes the goals of someone who aspires to be a rock star.

Comment: Absolutely the best option, and not without precedence: _sex, drugs and rock'n'roll_...

Comment: @oerkelens Thanks! That use of the expression really convinced me of this option and made me accept it! I think the answer would benefit from including it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sample sentence: Humans desire riches, fame, power and… (wo)men?

The word women here is not viewed as an appropriate umbrella term by the OP.

collocation: "Riches, power, fame and women"

new suggested collocation: Wealth, power, fame and sexual conquests.

Sexual conquests does not limit the meaning to women. It extends it to all humans regardless of sexual orientation or gender.

Merriam Webster: b : a person whose favor or hand has been won

Please note, I changed riches to wealth also. No reference for that, just intuition.

[conquest](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conquest)

[sexual conquest + Picasso](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/science/the-fine-art-of-sexual-conquest-277381.html)

Answer (score 1):

Riches, fame, power, and [**lovers**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lover).

> **b** : a person with whom one has sexual relations · He was her first *lover*.

I think this is as close as you can get to a non-gender and non-orientation specific version of *women* that still uses it in the sense that you define.

---

Speaking in terms of the grammar, however, note that there is an issue with parallelism in both this and the original.

The first three nouns are all uncountable and conceptual. They talk about ideas. In the original, *women* is being used as a mass noun, but it has less of a conceptual focus.

To more accurately preserve parallelism, a more accurate phrase might be riches, fame, power, and [**sex**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sex):

> 3 a : sexually motivated phenomena or behavior

Answer (score 0):

The most generic and appropriate term would only be *pleasures.*

Also, *egg in one's beer*.

Fleetwood, "The Life of Our Blessed Lord." [p.40](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=9XuFiRLMjukC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=%22profits%20and%20pleasures%22%20-bee&source=bl&ots=fKpygu2zC8&sig=g9IaLVpuOeo7uu2Udg6I4CI8bIY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu7MiDy-7bAhVFpo8KHT7fBW8Q6AEIQjAI#v=onepage&q=%22profits%20and%20pleasures%22%20-bee&f=false):

> … and first followed him with a view of obtaining honours, profits, and pleasures, in their posts under him.

Today we call it [*perks*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/perk) (perquisites) ODO.

> *informal*
>   **1A** benefit to which one is entitled because of one's job.
>   ‘many agencies are helping to keep personnel at their jobs by providing perks’

Comment: Could you provide example(s) of use?

Comment: I don't think *perk* works in this context. `But, it would make sense that at least a few wizards would want to use their powers to gain riches, fame, *perks* and power.`. *"Pleasures"* is a good suggestion, though. Maybe expanding it to "carnal pleasures" to focus it even more, if the specific sentence requires it?

Comment: Is that what 'egg in ones beer' means? Eww

Comment: @Mitch It's a clean word, don't worry. It just means an unexpected throw-in or bonus, sort of.

Comment: That and "perks" are pretty generic, they wouldn't be understood as referring specifically to sex. In fact, all the things in the list would be considered perks of their position.

Comment: @Barmar My answer was *pleasures* first and foremost. I cited *perks* as a sort of contemporary euphemism. In the given context, it amply serves the purpose. "... all the things in the list would be considered perks" itself shows that when followed by the word *perks* itself would naturally imply "other and unmentionables" or such. Get the drift?

Answer (score -2):

*Concubine* or better yet *paramour* might work here. Most dictionaries (M-W, TFD, ODO) seem to suggest that the former term can only have a female referent, but that limitation appears to lack etymological basis:

> from Latin concubina, from con- ‘with’ + cubare ‘to lie’. [ODO]

In any case, *paramour* is not so limited.

I am, perhaps rashly, assuming that the plural form *women,* and its inclusion in a series of typical objects of *selfish* desire, together imply that the sexual pursuit in question is something baser than the pursuit of meaningful or romantic human connection.

Comment: You are, of course, right on your assumption that is "sexual pursuit", and not "romantic connection" the focus of desire, to the point that I think should add it to my question (I thought it was implied, but better to be sure)

Comment: Could you add an example of use of your proposals that sounds natural, please?

Comment: Ignoble wizards use magic in the selfish pursuit of power, prominence, paramours, and pelf.